# No completed or running application displayed on Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

When I launch my ANN script, everything works fine at console level, but nothing changes on the Spark web interface: The application is not displayed in Running Applications or Completed Applications. 
I created a config file spark-defaults.conf in which I put:

```
spark.master                     spark://master:7077
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               /opt/spark/eventLogging
```

I created a spark-event folder in /tmp to be able to run the command:

```
start-history-server.sh
```

which works without error.
I'm running under java 8 and I didn't install hadoop.
I also try this command:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 2G --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=/opt/spark/eventLogging ./<my_script.py>
```

The script:

```
#make the ANN

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Elephas_App').setMaster('local[4]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


# Initialising the ANN
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, input_dim=11))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(6))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
from elephas.utils.rdd_utils import to_simple_rdd
rdd = to_simple_rdd(sc, x_train, y_train)

from elephas.spark_model import SparkModel

spark_model = SparkModel(model, frequency='epoch', mode='asynchronous')
spark_model.fit(rdd, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)
```

But there’s no change in the code execution and on the web interface.

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you are seeing. When you submit a Spark app it launches a new UI at port 4040. Read more details here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. Currently I have executed again the start-history-server.sh command but I get a java error, as it happens after restarting the server, it must mean that the additions I made were not taken into account. I'll look into it. Unfortunately comments don't allow me to publish this error. Do you know how I could proceed?

Comment: Follow these instructions to setup history server: https://supergloo.com/spark-monitoring/spark-performance-monitoring-history-server/

Comment: Thanks a lot I will follow the instructions you gave me. Now, I'm trying to install Hadoop, in order to use hdfs command. Hope it will helps.

Comment: you don't need hadoop. you can point to local file system

Comment: @AravindYarram start-history-server.sh works now. But when I execute the command: spark-submit --master spark://master.home:7077 ./elephas_ann.py nothing happens on the dashboard... I really don't understand why, I followed all the instructions on lot of websites.

Comment: I found the issue, in fact in my code I had put .setMaster('local[4]') as attribute for spark configuration. I had to remove it and ask for execution with --master spark://master.home:7077 in the command. I would like to put it as an answer but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: In fact spark takes into account first the script config, then the command config, then the general config. However, in my script, I had put

```
.setMaster("local[4]")
```

, and this expression took precedence over the command. And if you put local[], spark won't display the application. So I removed the instruction .setMaster("local[4]") from my script and typed this command:

```
spark-submit --master spark://MASTER_NODE:7077 ./MY_SCRIPT.py
```

Note that I could have written

```
.setMaster("spark://MASTER_NODE:7077")
```

in my script, and it would have worked, too.

Now it works.